# c++ vector = {vec1.begin, vec1.begin} returns empty vector

Tags: c++, iterator, stdvector, list-initialization

I'm trying to understand the behavior of creating a subvector of another vector.

For example, this code: https://godbolt.org/z/PYG34vnTr has a 2-element vector `vec1`. I want to create a vector of the first element. To get it to work, I had to use:

```
std::vector<int> vec2 = {vec1.begin(), vec1.begin() + 1};
```

I'm trying to understand why this is needed. Reason being, I'm doing a recursive loop that halves a vector in each iteration. And the formula:

```
std::vector<int> vec2 = {vec1.begin(), vec1.begin() + (vec1.size()-1)/2};
```

Works for all iterations except the one where `vec1` is a 2-element vector.

What alternative code should I use?

Comment: The second iterator is exclusive, it should be one past the last position you want to include.

Comment: Why not just `{vec1.begin(), vec1.begin() + vec1.size()/2}`?

Comment: Think about it - if `vec1.size()` is `2`, then `2-1` is `1`, and `1/2` is `0` in integer division, thus you are iterating from `begin` inclusive to `begin+0` exclusive, thus the resulting `vector` is empty. In the first example, iterating from `begin` inclusive to `begin+1` exclusive yields only 1 element, not 2.

Comment: Side note: most of the time, you want to just pass iterators to the function, rather than a copy of the data. For example, a binary search that copies the relevant half of the vector in each recursive call will end up O(N) instead of the O(log N) you'd normally hope for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The end iterator needs to be 1 element beyond the last element you want, which means that the `-1` must be removed.

Illustration:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void foo(std::vector<int> inp) {
    for (auto v : inp) std::cout << ' ' << v;
    std::cout << '\n';

    if (inp.size() > 1) {
        // the midpoint:
        auto mid = inp.begin() + inp.size() / 2;

        std::cout << "L:";
        foo({inp.begin(), mid});

        std::cout << "R:";
        foo({mid, inp.end()});
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec1{1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::cout << "X:";
    foo(vec1);
    std::cout << "Done\n";
}
```

Output:

```
X: 1 2 3 4
L: 1 2
L: 1
R: 2
R: 3 4
L: 3
R: 4
Done
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YrGEKG7Y4)

---

A non-copying version, working solely with iterators could look like this and gives the same result:

```cpp
template<class It>
void foo(It first, It last) {
    for(auto curr = first; curr != last; ++curr) std::cout << ' ' << *curr;
    std::cout << '\n';
    auto size = std::distance(first, last);

    if (size > 1) {
        auto mid = first + size / 2;
        std::cout << "L:";
        foo(first, mid);
        std::cout << "R:";
        foo(mid, last);
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E91z6veMW)